# Automatic vector resizing

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic, data-structures

I have a vector `std::vector<Data> v` that is initialised using the default constructor. If I call `v[2]`, there is likely a segmentation fault. My question is, is there any data structure that allows the following?

1. Can be cleared using a simple `v.clear()` method.
2. When I call `v[n]`, all elements `v[0..n-1]` are initialised using the default constructor of `Data`.

Comment: No, there isn't. But what's great about C++, is that you can write and implement your own data structure that works exactly as you've described. Good luck!

Comment: just [`resize`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) a vector

Comment: @Thomas I'm afraid that it is too costly. I don't want to be running thousands of `if` statements checking whether a `resize` is needed or not per second.

Comment: [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) may not do exactly what you say, but it will default initialize a value for keys that does exist when you call `operator[]`(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). Though, I'd lean toward just providing [a function that you can call before such vector assignments](http://ideone.com/VQmup5).

Comment: @HenryW. Unfortunately, whether *you* do that check, or the data structure does the check, somebody has to do it, and it will cost something. If this needs to be high performance, hopefully you can allocate upfront since the reallocation you're looking for itself isn't cheap.

Comment: What do you mean by `all elements v[0..n-1]`. If I call `v[1]` and then `v[2]`   the I would expect only `v[2]` to get default constructed.

Comment: You don't need to check. just replace `v[n]` with `v.resize(n+1);v[n]`; Someone has to check either way.

Comment: `I'm afraid that it is too costly` : Beware of premature optimizations and false assumptions. Measure!. Branch predictions sometimes may work for you.